# How to find all string without 'http://' at the beginning with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an `Object` that has an attribute or `url`.

```
>> Object.url
=> "http://www.sweetObject.org"
```

But some url's do not have `http://` in front of them.

How does a pious programmer create a find in ActiveRecord that can find all url strings without the `http://` at the beginning of the string?

**my attempt**

```
Object.find(:all, :conditions => ["url = ?", match(/http:\/\//) ] )
```

..which horribly fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why regex?

```
Object.find(:all, :conditions => ["url not like ?", "http://%" ] )
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Active(Model|Record) have an abstraction for regex based finders. The best I could come up with is (rails-3, ruby-1.9.2)

```
Object.where('url NOT REGEXP ?', '^http://')
```